# Server 500 error - moved app in subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I developed an application in a subfolder of my website and it worked fine.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|swf|uploads|js|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This file was working fine so and index.php was not required to navigate within the application. Now I moved the application to root of website and changes the last line to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now I have start getting Internal Server Error 500. I am not sure that it is something I have done or the .htacces is required to be configured differently. It might be an issue with host too, but I want to exhaust my options first.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you in root of hosting you just need

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|swf|uploads|js|css|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

if you site in folder `/foo` you need:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /foo
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|swf|uploads|js|css|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo/index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

if still not working try this, for me it works all over:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks man, you are a life saver. I always get stuck with .htaccess file. I think time to learn the internals has come.

Comment: @AmanAujla lol i wish one day i could save some life, anyway these are simple starting problems once you get how that works it's easy ;)