# Moving working CodeIgniter website to subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have a perfectly working website working as the root of my webhost (/public_html), but I recently bought a new domain and parked it there too, so I needed a subdir for it (/public_html/newdomaindir).

Now I need to move my entire website to a subfolder (/public_html/website) and I'm having a hard time adapting the .htaccess files.

This was my old working .htaccess file when it was root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.org$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.website\.org\/" [R=301,L]

#SetEnvIfNoCase Host ^www\.website\.org$ require_auth=true

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|robots\.txt|js|icons|files|fonts|extplorer)
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?/$1[L,QSA]
```

And now the webhost support suggest that I have this .htaccess file as root, to redirect traffic.

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} website.org$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !website/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ website/$1
```

But, well... it's not working as expected. My website is broken.

Should I use a different approach, maybe ask the support guys to change the document_root of my website? Should I change anything in the subfolder .htaccess file?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried by changing `base url` in CI config file

Comment: This should not change. It is still `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.website.org/';`

Comment: Please try by changing `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.website.org/';`  to  `$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.website.org/website';`  with original .htaccess

Answer (score 2):

Not my strongest skill, but I would try to modify your previous `.htaccess` to following form:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.org$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.website\.org\/" [R=301,L]

# not sure what about this
#RewriteCond $1 !^website\/(index\.php|images|css|robots\.txt|js|icons|files|fonts|extplorer)
RewriteRule ^$ website/ [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ website/index.php?/$1[L,QSA]
```

If this does not work, maybe you will find some clues in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15851064/4615331).

Comment: Got it working with RewriteBase, instead of changing the RewriteRules